# "Attempt to Upsert a Null List" in Lightning Helper Component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-design-system

I have created a simple Account Input page. Once I click submit button it has to create a new account but it is not creating and also not throwing any error.

And when I see in developer log it is throwing

> "System.NullPointerException: Attempted to upsert a null list".

Please check the below code:

Helper:

```
({  

    createAccount : function(component, Account) {

            console.log('inside helper');
            var action = component.get("c.saveAccount");
            console.log('after method called ');
            action.setParams({
                "Account ": Account 
            });
        action.setCallback(this, function(response){
            var state = response.getState();
            if (component.isValid() && state === "SUCCESS") { 
                var accounts = component.get("v.accounts"); 
                accounts.push(response.getReturnValue()); 
                component.set("v.accounts", accounts); 
            }
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
        },
    })
```

Apex class:

```
 public class NewAccountHandler {
    @AuraEnabled
    public static Account saveAccount(Account Account) { 
        system.debug('***--' + Account);
        upsert Account; 
        return Account;
    }
}
```

JS Controller

```
clickCreateAccount : function(component, event, helper) { 
   var validAccount = true; 
   var accnme = component.find("fstname");
   var aname = accnme.get("v.value"); 
    if (($A.util.isEmpty(aname))){
        validAccount = false; 
        accnme.set("v.errors", [{message:"Name can't be blank."}]); 
    }
    else {
        accnme.set("v.errors", null);
    } 
    if(validAccount){
        var newAccount = component.get("v.newaccount");
        console.log("Create Account: " + JSON.stringify(newAccount));
        helper.createAccount(component,newAccount);
    }
},
```

})

Comment: Can you update the post to include your JS controller as well please.

Comment: Are you getting the "Account" values appropriately in your apex? Have you verified if it is not null?

Comment: What are you trying to do ? What does your input look like, it appears your passing an empty Account to your js controller.  To me there are a few obvious things you are missing before you should ever attempt to save

Comment: I have included JS controller. Please look into it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if it's just a typo here or also in your code on salesforce, but I've spotted an extra space inside the quotes

```
      action.setParams({
            "Account ": Account 
        });
```

In general be extra careful with names: case-sensitive, spaces, etc.

One of my colleagues lost hours struggling to find upper/lowercase typo in one attribute name... usually no errors/warnings will show up and you typically see just silent failures. warnings in the browser console would be nice and helpful but often missing.